# Validation in a Mediatr behaviour pipeline

Tags: c#, unity-container, fluentvalidation, mediatr

I am using the Mediatr 4 with my web api 2 project. Together with FluentValidation and Unity I have been adding a pipeline behaviour to validate my requests.

```
public class ValidationBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> _validators;

    public ValidationBehavior(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)
    {
        _validators = validators;
    }

    public Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext(request);
        var failures = _validators
            .Select(v => v.Validate(context))
            .SelectMany(result => result.Errors)
            .Where(f => f != null)
            .ToList();

        if (failures.Count != 0)
        {
            throw new ValidationException(failures);
        }
        return next();
    }
}
```

This all works fine but I would really like to be able to return the validation in a wrapped up response. I am struggling to make a change like this and either get it to compile or no have Unity throw runtime resolve issues.

I was thinking of having something like:

```
public class CommandResult : IResponseBase
{
    private List<ValidationFailure> _validationFailures = new List<ValidationFailure>();
    private readonly string _correlationid;

    public CommandResult(string correlationid)
    {
        _correlationid = correlationid;
    }
    public bool IsSuccess => _validationFailures.Count == 0;

    public static implicit operator bool(CommandResult result)
    {
        return result.IsSuccess;
    }

    public void AddFailures(List<ValidationFailure> results)
    {
        _validationFailures = results;
    }

    public List<ValidationFailure> Failures => _validationFailures;

    public string CorrelationId => _correlationid;
}
```

On this basis I add a constraint into the behaviour along the lines of:

```
public class ValidationBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
    where TResponse : IResponseBase, new()
```

but trying to return a CommandResult rather than throwing an exception is giving me type conversion issues, and it feels like I am making it far too complicated and I am missing something quite basic.

Comment: Where yours validation rules for this approach?

Comment: @Alexsandro_xpt if you look at the documentation for FluentValidation (https://fluentvalidation.net/start) you define your rules in external classes. These are then injected into the Validation behaviour by use of your preferred DI Container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me suggest another approach for your problem. Instead of a pipeline use custom ActionFilterAttribute to perform validation before your request hit controller and have to be routed by mediatr. The following example using Autofac as a container, but i hope you will get the idea and be able to modify the code appropriately. As a bonus - no changes are needed in your Mediatr requests or handlers. Validation will be performed before controller action called and execution won't go further until you have valid request.

```
public class ValidateModelStateFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IAutofacActionFilter
{
    private readonly IValidatorFactory _factory;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="factory"></param>
    public ValidateModelStateFilter(IValidatorFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionContext"></param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        base.OnActionExecutingAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);

        IEnumerable<object> parameters = actionContext.ActionArguments.Select(x => x.Value).Where(x => x != null);
        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            Type argumentType = parameter.GetType();
            if (argumentType == typeof(int) || argumentType == typeof(string))
            {
                continue;
            }
            IValidator validator = _factory.GetValidator(argumentType);
            if (validator != null)
            {
                ValidationResult validationResult = validator.Validate(parameter);
                if (!validationResult.IsValid)
                {

                   // place your formatting logic here. 
                    actionContext.Response = <your formatted response>;
                }
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: The whole point of a thing like MediatR is to introduce cross-cutting concerns which get tied up with the command/query so it would be handled by MediatR pipeline and everything would be contained within that one, compact unit. 

By using OnActionExecutingAsync, you're making things less explicit, more scattered around the codebase and a bit harder to manage.

Answer (score 3):

There are**Two** types of validation (*At least*)

1. Request data validation - Validate that received HTTP request contains required data in correct format. Ex. **Email** field is required and should be valid email address**
2. Domain-specific validation - Validate that modification which `Command` tries to apply to current application state is valid from **domain prospective**. Ex. **Email** must be unique. **Email** shouldn't be **blacklisted**.

The first type of validation goes into the `ActionFilter`.

The second type of validation goes into the `IPipelineBehavior`

[Domain Command Patterns - Validation](https://jimmybogard.com/domain-command-patterns-validation/)

Comment: While I agree in principle, won't you end up duplicating the Request validation in the Domain validator, as the domain validator can't trust the client?

Comment: @Cocowalla By "client" you mean `Controller.Action` which is creating command and sending it to domain, or let's say browser which sends a request?

Answer (score 0):

I like this quote:

> it feels like I am making it far too complicated and I am missing something quite basic.

This question is over 5 years old now, so this question might not reflect your code base anymore, but questions like this still seem to pop up and articles are written about this subject.

I don't understand why so many people want to use all kinds of generic interfaces to just add validation to requests.

First people need multiple hours to set it up, then there is a discussion on how to return a result (indeed throwing an exception is bad design, but returning a useful object should not be so hard?) and with each update of the MediatR package you need to worry whether all the registrations still work.

I have become very excited about [IGet](https://github.com/dotnet-IGet/IGet) that allows you to create "pipelines" via stupid simple code, just explicitly getting and invoking handlers via an outer handler. IGet just instantiates classes with their dependencies injected and you can do with that whatever you like:

```cs
public class MyRequestXPipeline
{
    private ILogger<MyRequestXPipeline> _logger;
    private IGet i;

    public MyRequestXPipeline(IGet iget, ILogger<MyRequestXPipeline> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        i = iget;
    }

    public async Task<Result<WhatWasAskedFor>> Handle(RequestX request)
    {
        var validationResult = i.Get<MyRequestXValidator>().Validate(request);
        if (!validationResult.IsValid)
        {
            return Result.Fail<WhatWasAskedFor>(validationResult.Message);
        }

        var whatWasAskedFor = i.Get<RequestXMainHandler>().Handle(request);

        var notification = new RequestXSucceeded { RequestX = request };
        await i.Get<NotificationPublisher<RequestXSucceeded>>().PublishAsync(notification);

        // call other handlers, maybe do more stuff.

        return Result.Success(whatWasAskedFor);
    }
}
```

Instead of relying on interface registrations and MediatR calling `await next()`, you now explicitly see what the "pipeline" does.